# Word: How to have mix styles in headline

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to have a title like this:

[image]

*Introduction* is a title of chapter 1. I want Word to understand that so when I create a table of contain, it can display *1  Introduction*.

How can I do this? Thank you.